# VB.NET - form inside a panel resize

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2013, tablelayoutpanel

I can't figure this out! I've researched docking, anchoring etc. but I'm yet to get it to correctly resize when the parent form resizes.

Edit:

Quick Overview:

I have a main form with a menustrip docked to the top and a panel set to fill. I have links within the menustrip which open forms within the panel. See code below. I am struggling to get the form within the panel to resize with the panel.

I've set the panel background to black and my form inside the panel to white. I can see the panel resizing with the form correctly. The form within the panel stays in its original position. If i start my app in maximized, then click on my menustrip sure enough the form within the panel resizes correctly. However, once it is maximized it doesn't shrink with the form like the panel container does.

**I've deleted everything on my whole form, added 1 panel to it and set to fill then on form load do the following:**

```
Dim f As New Contactdetails With {.TopLevel = False, .AutoSize = True}
    f.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    Me.Panel2.Controls.Add(f)
    f.Show()
```

**This still doesn't work. When i maximize my main form, the form inside the panel does not resize but the panel does as i've changed it's background to monitor its change in size**

Comment: I do a guess: Whatever you load into the panel as a child, make sure you set it's `DockStyle` to `Fill`, or it won't fill out the panel, which in turn fills into the cell of the `TableLayoutPanel`. Is it that what you missed?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've already done that. It works if i click my menustrip whilst maximized it then fills it up, but when i minimize the form the panel is still stretched.

Comment: So annoying! All the settings appear right. TableLayoutPanel is set to fill. Panel inside TableLayPanel is set to fill, and the Menustrip button is setting the panel DockStyle.Fill when the form is launched. It just doesn't resize the panel with maximize and minimize :(

Comment: The panel fill's when i do the initial form launch, but once open it will not resize with the main form.

Comment: Doesn't sound like you need the TableLayoutPanel if the form only has a menu strip and a child form in the body.  Remove the panel and just set the child form to dock.fill.

Comment: LarsTech, i have lots of child forms which are launched into the panel from the menustrip. So i need the panel? I've tried having just the menu strip and the panel set to fill but it only fills once, after that clicking the minimize/maximize on the main form doesn't change the panels size.

Comment: It transpires that the panel is infact changing with the form. It's the form within the panel that's not changing with the panel. Ideas?

Comment: Still no joy. Panel is re-sizing with the main form. However, the form inside the panel is not re-sizing after the first time it's launched. It fills the panel initially, but any subsequent minimize or maximize only the panel resizes.

Comment: Do you really need a `System.Windows.Forms.Form` (how are you even doing that), or wouldn't a `UserControl` be better? Can you try placing a `UserControl` in there and see if it stretches?

Comment: Post some code so we can see what you are doing.  Use the @ symbol in comments to reply to someone.

Comment: @LarsTech sorry, i'm still geting used to this site! I've edited the original with the code

Comment: We still don't have enough information.  Do you have the MaximumSize property set on the form?

Comment: @LarsTech yes i have set that on the form which loads into the panel.

Comment: And you are wondering why the form won't resize larger?  Set the property back to `0, 0`.

Comment: @LarsTech do you mean the form size? i've set it to 0,0 and it now grows from the original form size to maximized, but it will not go back to the original form size when i click minimize.

Comment: You said "yes i have that on the form which loads *into* the panel".  So you indicated you have set the MaximumSize property of the child form.  And I am telling you set that property back to `0, 0`.  If that doesn't cure it, you will have to post code that duplicates the problem for us.  Right now, this is just a guessing game.

Comment: @LarsTech Yes thats correct, the reason i set it to maximized is because when a user clicks another form you can't see it because it hides behind the first one. Changing it to normal and setting the size to 0,0 on form load half works. It maximizes and resizes the child form, but when i minimize the form is stretched.

Comment: This is going nowhere.  Post the minimal amount of code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @LarsTech you're telling me lol. The code which i use to produce the problem is up top. I have created a new blank form. Set it's size to 1330, 635. Put a panel on the form set to fill. I then created a second form with 2 buttons anchored to top left and top right. On form load event i put the above code. When i maximize the form the top right button follows the panel. When i minimize the top right button stays out of view.

Comment: Try `AutoSize = False`

Comment: @lartech YES!! you did it, i think it has been a combination of all of the above! Much appreciated! Now i need to know how to make sure that when someone launches a new form in the panel that it sits on top... you wouldnt happen to know that too? might be a new question needed! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn AutoSize off:

```
Dim f As New Contactdetails With {.TopLevel = False, .AutoSize = False}
f.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
Me.Panel2.Controls.Add(f)
f.Show()
```

If the previous form in the panel isn't being used anymore, then you should first dispose of it:

```
While Me.Panel2.Controls.Count > 0
  Me.Panel2.Controls(0).Dispose()
End While
```

Comment: Cheers! I've tried your second suggestion and that didn't work. But you solved my original question, many thanks!

Comment: @Matt Don't forget to accept the answer with the tick on the left.

Answer (score 0):

Set the WindowState to Normal in properties of the child form

and

```
Me.Dock = DockStyle.
```

Fill in the Load sub of the child form